# reading multiple files in while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a list of .gz files,like:

```
abc-1.1.0-abc.tar.gz
abc-1.2.3-hfc.tar.gz
hfg-1.8.9-jdh.tar.gz
```

Content of file_name:

```
abcd_name_fb
hsgdh_name_cd
```

in my scipt, i'm capturing the strings '1.1.0,1.2.3,1.8.9' from the file names and i need to pass these strings as a 3rd argument/parameter.

Basically, my script looks like this:

```
if [[ "$#" -ne '3' ]]
then
    exit 1
fi

for i in /home/dir/*.gz
do
    n=$( echo $i |sed -E -n 's/.*\-(.*)\-.*/\1/p')
    echo $n
done > /home/dir/n.txt

while read -r name
do
if [[ "$1" == "some_string" ]] && [[ "$name" == "$2" ]] || [[ "$2" == "ALL" ]]
then
mkdir -p /home/ce/pwde/${name}
fi
done < /home/file_name
```

I'm unable to figure out how to read the file n.txt for validating the 3rd parameter and at the same time reading the file file_name.

I'm executing my script from the terminal as:

```
./script.sh some_string ALL 1.2.3
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to visit https://www.shellcheck.net/ to first get rid of typos and syntax issues.

Comment: @Thomas : I guess, the syntax is fine..has no issue.

Comment: What content does the `file_name."$1"` have? It is not clear from your question. You also might want to show how you call your script and which error is spit.

Comment: @Thomas : I've updated my question. Basically, I'm not able to find out how to validate the 3rd parameter , i'm tring to use a nested while loop,first reading the file`n.txt` to read the 3rd parameter and then the file `file_name.A` to read the `line` to perform `ops` function.

Comment: It may be useful to add the kind of validation you want for your third positional argument. E.g. are you trying to read `n.txt` line by line and check if `$3` equals one of them? Also, the nested loop from your previous comment might be a way. Have you tried it? It may be worth adding your attempt to the code you posted.

Comment: Ahh...nested while loop worked..Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, earlier my mind was wandering somewhere else, now i used below nested while loop and it's working:

```
while read -r n
do
  if [[ "$3" == "$n" ]]
  then
    while read -r name || [[ -n "$name" ]]
    do
      if [[ "$1" == "some_string" ]] && [[ "$name" == "$2" ]] || [[ "$2" == "ALL" ]]
      then
        mkdir -p /home/ce/pwde/${name}
      fi
    done < /home/file_name
  fi
done < /home/dir/n.txt
```

Comment: It would none the less be good if the question could be updated with the overall goal of this exercise. Going via a temporary file seems needless, but it's hard to tell whether there's an easier way to do this without knowing what it is you'd like to do.